What to look out for when creating Case record types for the first time in an old org
I've done an extensive web search and come up empty -- either there's nothing out there, or I can't find it in the sea of everything else related to creating Case record types....
In an org with lots of Case records and current Cases still being created, there has never been a Case record type. Now there is a need for a totally different type of Case that will have different fields, routing, picklist values, etc.
It has been decided that a new Case record type is the way to go.  The "old" original Cases need to be the default Case type.
Other than...

Creating one new Case record type to be the default for the "old" type Cases,
Selecting our default Support Process to associate with it,
Updating any current Case code to look at the new record type (if applicable),

...is there anything else we need to do or worry with, or are there any "gotchas" that I'm not seeing when trying to wedge in a new "old" record type where none existed?
And do we need to "convert" all the old non-typed Case records to the new "old" record type before we create the real new record type that will be used for the new Case types?

Default record types suck - be explicit about this change and assign some (newly created) record type to the old cases.

having done this several times, I agree with identigral.  Personally, I'd convert all the old Cases to have a recordType using Data Loader or its equivalent.  Be worth verifying that the update won't initiate any triggers/flows/WFR/Process Builders that have unintended consequences.
